# Getting inner class field values using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, inner-classes

I am trying to access inner class field values using reflection.

Suppose the classes are:-

```
public class OuterClass  {
    int a;
    public class InnerClass {
        int b;
        InnerClass(int b){
            this.b = b;
       }
    }

    public void setInnerField(int val){
        InnerClass a = new InnerClass(val);
    }
}
```

And the main function has:-

```
OuterClass obj = new OuterClass();
obj.a = 10;
obj.setInnerField(5);
```

Following is what I am trying to get the inner class field value i.e. b
Referred from [How i can access inner class variable value using reflection in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218419/how-i-can-access-inner-class-variable-value-using-reflection-in-java)

```
Class[] classes = obj.getClass().getDeclaredClasses();     
for(Class innerClass: classes){
    //System.out.println(innerClass.getName());
    Field[] fields = innerClass.getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field field : fields){
        //System.out.println(field.getName());
        System.out.println(field.get(obj));  //<-----IllegalArgumentException    
//Tried with below line too as suggested in above link                                                                     
System.out.println(field.get(innerClass.getInterfaces())); //<-----IllegalArgumentException
    }           
}
```

Then what can be  the ways to access the inner class field values at runtime?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. But note that when you call `setInnerField(5)` you are creating an `InnerClass` instance, but immediately throwing it away. You don't have any object of the type `InnerClass` at that point, so you can't access any field.

Comment: Your inner class is not a member of the outer class (outer class has no field `private InnerClass inner;`), therefore it is not accessible.

Comment: @matoni strictly speaking, any inner class is a member of its outer class. Perhaps you mean that there is no *field* in the outer class that is an *instance* of the inner class.

Comment: it's throwing Illegal arg exception in filed.get(obj) because the parameter is not of the type that declares the field, which is in the doc of get() method:
"If the specified object is not an instance of the class or interface declaring the underlying field, the method throws an IllegalArgumentException. "

you are passing it obj of type OuterClass to obtain field OuterClass$InnerClass.b
so either you have an instance of the InnerClass and pass it to filed.get(innerObj) or declare your inner class and it's fields as a static members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code throws IllegalArgumentException because:

```
`System.out.println(field.get(obj));
 System.out.println(field.get(innerClass.getInterfaces()));// your inner class does not implement any interfaces which result in [] as an arg`
```

the obj arg you pass to get method has to be of the the same type that declares the field you invoke get on which in this case OuterClass$InnerClass.**b**

this already documented for the get method:

> If the specified object is not an instance of the class or interface declaring the underlying field, the method throws an IllegalArgumentException.

Either you declare your innerclass and it's field as a static or you have an instance of your inner class and pass it as an arg to the field.get(**innerInstance**) when you invoke it on the inner class fields